# How does the Space Jockey’s chair work?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

I have searched Google, but no joy. Are there details about the chair the Space Jockey is sitting in in *Alien* — what it does, and how it functions in relation to the space craft?

Comment: Have you seen Prometheus?

Comment: Of course ! Just seeing if someone had written anything plausible on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

As seen in '[Prometheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_(2012_film))' (and I think several interviews and DVD commentaries with Ridley Scott over the years since Alien was released) it's the pilot's seat. Though given the bio-mechanical nature of their technology and how it seems to connect with the Jockey's suit, "seat" may be an oversimplification. "Control interface" may be closer to the mark.